# How to use a variable date when running a db2 command in a shell script?

Tags: db2, unix

I need to use a date variable in a `select`, like bellow, but I'm getting this error: *Expected tokens may include:  "".  SQLSTATE=42601*

How can use these variables in a shell script?

```
day0_T1=`TZ=CST+12 date +"%Y-%m-%d %T"`
day0_T0=`TZ=CST+24 date +"%Y-%m-%d %T"`
dayn_Tn=`TZ=CST+n date +"%Y-%m-%d %T"`

db2 connect to BD
db2 "/path/result.tmp  OF DEL MODIFIED BY COLDEL; decplusblank striplzeros
select count(*),user from table1
and close_datetime between cast(date('$day0_T0') as timestamp) AND cast(date('$day0_T1') as timestamp)
and task = 'task1' 
group by user
with ur"
db2 terminate
```

Comment: I think you're missing the `export` command itself.

Comment: Not to mention `SELECT blah FROM table1 AND...` is a little odd. I would've expected a `WHERE` clause instead of the `AND`.

Answer (score 1):

Shell quotes typically delimit arguments or escape other special shell characters from shell interpretation. You can contain (and therefore escape) different kinds of shell-quotes within other kinds based on various rules:

- `"''''"` - a soft-quoted string can contain any number of hard-quotes.
- `"\""` - a `\` backslash can escape a "soft-quote within a "soft-quoted string.
- In this context a `\\backslash` also escapes itself, the `\$expansion` token, and `\newlines` as noted below, but is otherwise treated literally.
- `"${expand} and then some"` - a soft-quoted string can contain an interpreted shell `$expansion`.
- `'"\'` - a 'hard-quoted string can contain any character other than a 'hard-quote.
- `\` - an unquoted backslash will escape any following character for literal interpretation - even another backslash - excepting a `\newline`.
- In a `\\newline` case both the `\` backslash and the `\newline` are completely removed from the resulting interpreted command.
  `${parameter+expand "$parameter"}` - quotes resulting from a shell expansion almost never serve as delimiter markers excepting a few special cases. I won't venture to describe these further here.

**Test:**

```
root@onare:/home/onare# echo $day0_T1
2015-07-16 14:10:44
root@onare:/home/onare# db2="something '${day0_T1}'"
root@onare:/home/onare# echo $db2
something '2015-07-16 14:10:44'
root@onare:/home/onare#
```

Comment: Hi oNare, my problem isn't related to shell, but to use a shell var in a db2 datababe select ... thnks anyway